# SceneBuilder Tooltip over Label JavaFX

Tags: javafx, label, tooltip, scenebuilder

If I have a label with a text that's too long and I want a tooltip that shows the entire label text when I hover over the label with my mouse. Is that possible to do in SceneBuilder or do I have to do it programically for all my labels?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Under "Miscellaneous" in the Library pane (left side), you will find a "Tooltip". Just drag it and drop it onto the label in the Hierarchy pane below. Then you can select the tooltip and configure the text, etc.

[image]

Comment: The problem I have is that the label is dynamic so the tooltip can't have a static text.

Comment: Just set an `fx:id` on the tooltip, and then you can access it in the controller to dynamically update the text.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought I would need to do. So many labels though=S. Thought there was an easier way in SceneBuilder. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: how to show multi-line tooltip text using scenebuilder?.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This option in scene builder has saved a lot of code for my toolbar.