# JavaFX 8: How can a tooltip be displayed when mouse rollover of a label occurs?

Tags: javafx, tooltip, scenebuilder

JavaFX 8: How can a tooltip be displayed when mouse rollover of a label occurs?

I am using SceneBuilder and have applied the following instructions, however, when the mouse is rolled over the label the tooltip doesn't appear:

[SceneBuilder Tooltip over Label JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162669/scenebuilder-tooltip-over-label-javafx?s=1|3.4877)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what have you done so far ?

Comment: The example that you have linked works perfectly when you hover the mouse over the node. Can you please explain what doesn't work and what have you tried?